# How many of the spanning trees, $K_n$ have vertex n as a leaf?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So I know that I should probably use Cayley's formula here, which is that for positive integer $n$, there are $n^{n-2}$ labeled trees on n vertices. So I looked at a few trees and saw that when n = 3 there are 3 trees, 2 of which can have the same vertex as a leaf. Then when n = 4, there are 16 trees. 9 of which can have the same vertex as a leaf. I am a little lost on how I am supposed to go from Cayley's formula to somehow counting the possibilities, any help would be appreciated here. Hopefully I am not going in the wrong direction here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: If vertex $n$ is a leaf, the rest of the spanning tree is a spanning tree for $K_{n-1}$. Conversely, a spanning tree for $K_{n-1}$ can be extended to how many spanning trees for $K_n$ having $n$ as a leaf?

Comment: So for n = 4, for example, The spanning tree of $K_{4 - 1}$ or $K_3$ gives 3 possible trees, there are 3 spots the vertex 4 can be inserted to be a leaf, so 3 possible trees * 3 possible spots = 9. This is (I think) the number of trees in the possible tree set of 4 vertices with vertex 4 as a leaf. So to generalize, it would be the number of spanning trees of $K_{n-1}$ or (using Cayley's formula) $(n-1)^{n-3}$ multiplied by the different spots that leaf vertex could be inserted to make it a leaf in each tree.

Comment: @wbrugato: That’s right.

Comment: Alright, great!! So can the number of different spots the leaf vertex could be inserted into each $K_{n-1}$ spanning tree just be generalized to n-1 spots?

Comment: @wbrugato: Yes: the leaf can be attached to any vertex of the existing tree.

Comment: thanks!! super helpful hint, really made me understand the question and what I was doing a lot more!!

Comment: @wbrugato: You’re welcome, and thank *you*!